# Creating multiple SQLite databases containing the same schema for a Flashcard program, bad practice?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am currently trying to come up with a way that I can import/export sets of data. I need to share a deck of flashcards. 
Each flashcard includes:

- Front Text `string`,
- Reverse Text `string`,
- eFactor `float`/`real`,
- interval `integer`,
- count `integer`

The idea is that I want users to create a deck of flashcards and have the ability to share that deck. The concept is very similar to that of decks / .anki files in `Anki`. At the moment I am using SQLite3 to store the flaschard data. I had considered using XML but I felt that SQL was a more logical approach.

My initial plan was to allow users to create multiple SQLite DB files because I felt there are some key advantages to this approach.

- 1) It is easier to share a db file rather than having to export a table from the SQLite database and then end up sharing a file anyway.
- 2) If the user wishes to delete the deck, it is as simple as deleting the db file.

As for the negatives though: I can understand that it maybe be seen as a waste of resources or 'messy' to create multiple SQLite fb files.

Is this method feasible or would it be considered to be bad programming practice? I'm open to different approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think having a separate .db file per deck is completely acceptable. As you mentioned, it allows for easier addition/removal of decks. Sharing of decks is much simpler also -- you can just send a file. This is much easier than the alternative of opening some "master deck" and then exporting the deck you wish to share.

There will not be very much duplicated data among each of the decks (some schema information), so it's not a big waste. You *will* have to be careful about versioning inside the decks if you change the scheme, however. That may be a bit trickier with multiple files.